# NVDA doesn't read content of role

Tags: html, nvda

NVDA doesn't read content of role. I didn't find actual info. It should read the value of role (option).

```
listItemsTemlate.push(
'<li id="', liId, '" name="', mediumValue, '" role="presentation">',
'<a title="', text, '" id="', linkId, '" role="option" aria-posinset="', (index + 1), '" aria-setsize="', array.length,
'" class="co_deliveryLinkOptions" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class="', self._GetIconClass(mediumValue), '"></span>', text, '</a>',
'</li>');
```

Comment: Not enough info in your question.  Is your `role="option"` contained in a parent with `role="listbox"`?  That's a requirement for the "option" role, https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#option

Comment: I found info, that only menuitemradio can be readed by srcreen reader. So, just need to change option to menuitemradio